Livewire no carga los atributos de un modelo
Buen día
La pregunta es un poco larga porque he probado muchas cosas pero espero que alguien pueda ayudarme a averiguar el problema.
Tengo un componente Livewire, actualicé de v2 a v3 y actualmente uso v3.5.4; El problema comenzó después de la actualización.
Mi modelo Vehicle tiene tres atributos, para ser breve solo mostraré uno:
public function getVersionsQAttribute()
{
    $brands = Brand::where('brand', $this->brand)
        ->pluck('brand_ws')
        ->toArray();

    $sub_brands = SubBrand::where('sub_brand', $this->sub_brand)
        ->pluck('sub_brand_ws')
        ->toArray();

    $versions = QVehicle::where('year', '=', $this->year)
        ->whereIn('brand', $brands)
        ->whereIn('sub_brand', $sub_brands)
        ->pluck('version', 'amis')
        ->toArray();

    return $versions;
}

En el componente Livewire, tengo una instancia del modelo para editar:
public Vehicle $editing;

En el método mount, tengo esto:
public function mount()
{
    $this->editing = $this->makeBlank();
}

El método makeBlank() es el siguiente:
public function makeBlank()
{
    return new Vehicle();
}

En la vista del componente Livewire muestro una tabla que tiene un botón en cada fila para editar el vehículo, esto abre un modal con algunas entradas y una de ellas es un input select:
<x-input.group for="createAmisQ-versions" label="VersionsQ" :error="$errors->first('editing.amis_q')" class="col-lg-2 col-3">
    <x-input.select wire:model="editing.amis_q" id="createAmisQ-versions" name="createAmisQ-versions">
        <option value=0 class="py-1">Select...</option>
        @foreach ($this->editing->versions_q as $amis => $version)
            <option wire:key="version-q-{{$amis}}" value="{{ $amis }}" class="py-1">{{ $version }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </x-input.select>
</x-input.group>

Cuando oprimo el botón de edición de cualquier fila, se ejecuta esto:
public function edit(Vehicle $vehicle)
{
    $this->useCachedRows();

    $this->editing = $vehicle;

    $this->showEditModal = true;
}

La tabla vinculada al modelo ya tiene datos, por lo que editing.amis_q ya tiene algún valur. Cuando se muestra el modal, la entrada de selección no muestra ninguna opción seleccionada y todas las versions_q están vacías, esto significa que solo la opción "Select..." se renderiza.
Si cierro el modal y oprimo en la edición de cualquier fila, incluso en el mismo botón que se oprimió anteriormente, versions_q tiene todas las versiones, se muestran todas las opciones y se muestra el input select con la opción seleccionada que contiene editing.amis_q.
Mi problema es que no entiendo por qué editing.versions_q no renderiza las opciones la primera vez que se abre el modal pero se renderizan correctamente la segunda vez que se abre el modal.
Intento 1
Usar dd($this->editing->toArray()) dentro del método edit y cada vez  puedo ver que contiene los datos correctos, incluso la primera vez que se abre el modal, por lo que no estoy seguro de por qué no se muestran la primera vez que se abre el modal.
Intento 2
Crear una propiedad Livewire calculada que reemplace el atributo del modelo, de esta forma:
#[Computed()]
public function versions()
{
    $brands = Brand::where('brand', $this->editing->brand)
        ->pluck('brand_ws')
        ->toArray();

    $sub_brands = SubBrand::where('sub_brand', '=', $this->editing->sub_brand)
        ->orWhere('sub_brand', 'like', '%' . $this->editing->brand . '%')
        ->pluck('sub_brand_ws')
        ->toArray();

    $versions_q = Vehicle::where('year', '=', $this->editing->year)
        ->whereIn('brand', $brands)
        ->whereIn('sub_brand', $sub_brands)
        ->pluck('version', 'amis')
        ->toArray();

    return [
        'q' => $versions_q,
    ];
}

Y modificó el @foreach en la vista, así:
@foreach ($this->versions['q'] as $amis => $version)

Pero sigue teniendo el mismo problema, solo se carga la segunda vez que se abre el modal.
Intento 3
Pensé que tal vez las consultas de Eloquent estaban tomando demasiado tiempo, así que traté de optimizarlas a esto:
#[Computed()]
public function versions()
{
    $versions_q = Vehicle::query()
        ->select('vehicles.version', 'vehicles.amis')
        ->join('brands', 'brands.brand_ws', '=', 'vehicles.brand')
        ->join('sub_brands', function($join) {
            $join->on('sub_brands.sub_brand_ws', '=', 'vehicles.sub_brand')
                ->where('sub_brands.sub_brand', '=', $this->editing->sub_brand)
                ->orWhere('sub_brands.sub_brand', 'like', '%'.$this->editing->brand.'%');
            })
        ->where('vehicles.year', '=', $this->editing->year)
        ->where('brands.brand', '=', $this->editing->brand)
        ->pluck('vehicles.version', 'vehicles.amis')
        ->toArray();

    return [
        'q' => $versions_q,
    ];
}

Esto proporciona la misma salida que tenía antes, pero el problema sigue presente, las opciones no se cargan la primera vez que se abre el modal y se cargan correctamente la segunda vez que se abre el modal.
Debo agregar que después de actualizar Livewire, he configurado el legacy_model_binding para mantener la misma funcionalidad que tenía.
'legacy_model_binding' => true

Si tienen alguna pista de por qué está sucediendo esto, me ayudaría mucho.
